# How to return HTML from a Go Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a Go program that serves wave information in html format when the a URL is hit. It was running on a VM with a nginx reverse proxy.

I am trying to move the code to AWS Lambda, but I am struggling to understand how to trigger and return the html.

The original code did its logic and presented is data as template HTML in the snip below.

```cs
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    GetWeather()
    GetSurf()
    CheckSurf(ForecastGroup)
    p := CodCallPage{Title: "Swell Forecast", RunTime: htmlRunDate, DailyHtmlData: DailyMatchingSwells}
    codcallTemplateInit.Execute(w, p)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8000", nil)
}
```

I believe I no longer need the nginx proxy and need to invoke the lambda function to run my code. So I have changed the code to the following.

```cs
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    GetWeather()
    GetSurf()
    CheckSurf(ForecastGroup)
    p := CodCallPage{Title: "Swell Forecast", RunTime: htmlRunDate, DailyHtmlData: DailyMatchingSwells}
    codcallTemplateInit.Execute(w, p)
}

func handler(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) error {
    log.Println("Via Lambda !!")
    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

When I run the AWS test, lamba function with the default JSON text.

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2",
  "key3": "value3"
}
```

It gives an error as it times out:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-06-08T08:43:13.714Z d6e2acc0-b1da-4e92-820b-63f8f5050947 Task timed out after 15.01 seconds"
}
```

I'm not sure if the test is being ignored by the lambda function or the function isn't returning the HTML in the correct way, or if the lambda function is expecting JSON rather than HTML ?  Any pointers to help me understand and where I should look, please?

Comment: Probably your `GetWeather()`, and other `Get*` functions timeout. You have to check if you actually can connect to whereever those calls attempt to connect.

Comment: Thanks but they work in the none Lambda. The answer by @yosher lutski below helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to run an http server on a lambda function. this code should work

```golang
func indexHandler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (string, error)  {
        GetWeather()
        GetSurf()
        CheckSurf(ForecastGroup)
        p := CodCallPage{Title: "Swell Forecast", RunTime: htmlRunDate, DailyHtmlData: DailyMatchingSwells}
        var res bytes.Buffer
        if err := codcallTemplateInit.Execute(&res, p); err != nil {
          return "", err 
        }
        return res.String(), nil
}


func main() {
        lambda.Start(indexHandler)
}
```

Using AWS API gateway proxy you'll need to return return `events.APIGatewayProxyResponse` so `indexHandler` will be different.

```golang
func indexHandler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error)  {
        GetWeather()
        GetSurf()
        CheckSurf(ForecastGroup)
        p := CodCallPage{Title: "Swell Forecast", RunTime: htmlRunDate, DailyHtmlData: DailyMatchingSwells}
        var res bytes.Buffer
        if err := codcallTemplateInit.Execute(&res, p); err != nil {
          return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{StatusCode: 400, Body: err.Error()}, err 
        }
        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{Body: res.String(), StatusCode: 200}, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you!. It works when I run the test function now I can see the html in the console. However when I assign an API Gateway trigger to invoke the function I get  the following in the browser "{"message":"Internal Server Error"}"  I've tried the HTTP API and the REST API triggers. My next quest :)

Comment: Hi @AndyM, I glad it helps, it'll be nice if you can mark it as the correct answer. for your next question, I will try returning an APIGatewayProxyResponse instead. I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: Thanks. I used your update to return APIGatewayProxyResponse. I'm now getting the error. "cannot use events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{…} (value of type events.APIGatewayProxyResponse) as string value in return statement". I'm looking at fixing that.

Comment: Many thanks yosher I now understand the return needed for the function to work correctl. . Fixed and working. For anyone else I corrected the return type in APIGatewayProxyResponse and had to set the headers := map[string]string{
                "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=UTF-8",
        }
for it to display the html.